# Simple.Data select a constant value into column

Tags: sql, simple.data

Is there a way with Simple.Data to add a column to a query where the column will just contain some constant? For example it would be similar to this query:

```
SELECT Name, 'Unpaid' AS Status FROM table;
```

I would like to do something similar to the 'Unpaid' part in this query.

Comment: This query looks spot on as it is.  Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hey Tim. Thanks for the input. Please note the "Simple.Data" part. It is a .NET ORM.

Comment: I don't know this API at all, but the cop out answer would be to just modify your underlying data structure to contain this temporary data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is an option but I would only use it as a last resort.